# How to connect from mininet to opendaylight which runs oxygen after installing odl-dluxapp features?

Tags: remote-access, connectivity, opendaylight, mininet

I'm trying to connect to opendaylight oxygen from a mininet which runs on a virtual machine on ubuntu. When I ran features:install odl-dluxapps-topology odl-restconf-all odl-l2switch-switch in the above order, the mininet connects to odl and shows the topology. But when I install odl-dluxapps-nodes, and tries to connect to odl, it says unable to connect to the remote server. The command I use to connect from mininet is sudo mn --topo linear,4 --mac --controller=remote,ip=10.34.0.193,port=6633 --switch ovs,protocols=Openflow13 . How do I connect to odl from mininet while accessing all the dluxapps features.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install all features in the same line command:

features:install odl-dluxapps-topology odl-restconf-all odl-l2switch-switch odl-dluxapps-nodes

See this for reference: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/release-notes/projects/distribution.html#known-issues